# C# same type and namespace in different merged assembly referenced by another one

Tags: c#, types, namespaces, ilmerge

I have a "common" project. Let's call it: MyProject.Common
This project has a namespace Serials.Licensing which contains a class License **with static variables**.

So this will be the structure of the common project:

```
MyProject.Common (dll)
| -> Serials.Licensing (namespace)
   | -> License (class with static variables)
```

Using IlMerge, I merge this assembly in two different assembly's (A.dll, B.dll). This will be the result of the 2 created assemblies with IlMerge:

```
   assemblyA (dll)
    | -> Serials.Licensing (namespace)
       | -> License (class with static variables)

    | class "classA" using the License class of this dll
```

And

```
   assemblyB (dll)
    | -> Serials.Licensing (namespace)
       | -> License (class with static variables)

    | class "classB" using the License class of this dll
```

As you can see, both the assemblies have classes (classA, classB) that use the License class merged in their own assembly

If in a new project (projectC), I reference both dll A and dll B. Will be there problems (such as conflicts) with the static variables in the class License?

I'm confused because I don't know if both dll A and dll B will have their own "context" or if there will be issues because the namespaces and types are the same as the static variables of the License class.

Comment: What's the scope of License? If you make it Internal does that help?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access something in the type you will get a compile error telling you, that the type License exists in both, A.dll and B.dll. So that won't work for you.
If you never access the type, the project should compile just fine.